# span disappears while data binding knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="panelFoot" data-bind="foreach:InvestmentArray ">
    <p class="text-center" data-bind="text: $data.ETE"> 
       <span data-bind="text:$data.symbol"></span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

The `span` disappears but when I move the `span` outside from the `p` it works. Very weird.

So is there a way to fix this?

Comment: two questions 
1) is there anything in InvestmentArray? 2) are there any javascript errors?

Comment: Yea there is arrays inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`text` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) sets the element’s content to a text node with your parameter value. **Any previous content will be overwritten.**

So your `text` binding on the `p` removes the `span` which is inside the `p`.

To fix this you need to move the binding inside the `p` with using the containerless syntax:

```
<div class="panelFoot" data-bind="foreach:InvestmentArray ">
    <p class="text-center" data-bind="">
        <!-- ko text: $data.ETE --><!-- /ko -->
        <span data-bind="text:$data.symbol"></span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

Or you can add another span:

```
<div class="panelFoot" data-bind="foreach:InvestmentArray ">
    <p class="text-center" data-bind="">
        <span data-dind="text: $data.ETE"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:$data.symbol"></span> 
    </p>
</div>
```